# Преобразование класса внутри массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть класс Sword, и его объект от него:sword
sword = Sword('name')
Но когда добавляешь элемент sword в список и пробуешь его отобразить, выдает тип объекта, а не sword.
Можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы когда выводишь массив, внутри объект sword был именно sword или sword.name, но сохранял все свои свойства(урон, прочность)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как-нибудь можно, но зачем?  Выводи сразу sword.name.

Comment: Код нужно вставлять текстом, а не изображением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переопределить в классе методы **str** и **repr**. Ниже пример.

```
class Sword:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __str__(self):
        return "Sword name= "+self.name
    def __repr__(self):
       return self.name

sw1=Sword("Mielnier")
sw2=Sword("Exalibur")
print(sw1)
print(sw2)
mass=[sw1,sw2]
print(mass)
```